# Mocking fluent API with Rhino

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, fluent-interface

I couldn't find any good way of mocking all methods for fluent API.
The best approach I have come by now is:

```
var builder = BindToSelf<IFluentBuilder>(
                x => x.WithA(),
                x => x.WithB("qwe"));
```

Is there a way to do somthing like this ?

```
var builder = BindToSelf<IFluentBuilder>(x => x.WithA().WithB("qwe"));
```

Or using reflection like this:

```
var builder = BindAllToSelf<IFluentBuilder>());
```

Something like this (this example doesn't work):

```
public static T ToSelfAll<T>(this T builder) where T : class
{
    foreach (MethodInfo item in typeof(T).GetMethods())
    {
        Func<T> action = (Func<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>), 
                                                          builder,
                                                          item.Name);
        builder.Expect(action).Return(builder);
    }
    return builder;
}
```

I am using Rhino Mocks.
What's your approach to mock fluent api?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's being asked. When you create a dynamic mock, all the methods of the interface are mocked to return their default values.